# How can I make an item both sortable (jQuery UI) and draggable (HTML5)?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list, using the jQuery UI sortable.  However, I also want items in the list to be draggable using HTML 5 (ie not jQuery UI Draggable).  The problem is, the sortable seems to override the draggable.  So, I have:

```
<ul id="my-folder-list" class="ui-sortable">
    <li draggable="true" item-id="6KXoILDr5K" ondragstart="drag(event);"><div>Winter 2012</div></li>
    <li draggable="true" item-id="WL2mL8emnH" ondragstart="drag(event);"><div>Summer 2012</div></li>
</ul>
```

And basically I want the folders to be sortable among themselves, but if one of them is dragged off to another div (a trashcan) then it should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at HTML5 Sortable which is a jQuery plugin to create sortable lists and grids using native HTML5 drag and drop API.

You'll find it here: http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but couldn't get it to work - there are a few places where I use the sortable, and it didn't seem to work properly for them.  I also have the sortable used in so many places that I'm reluctant to start pulling it all apart and rebuilding.  Thanks anyway, and I'll bear it in mind for the future.